# django rest framework defaultRouter without models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Python and Django (rest framework) and I love the DefaultRouter feature, by also giving an "API ROOT" page. But, I can only use the defaultrouter.register() method with viewsets. How to make a custom route without a model? For example I will have a "POST" route that multiplies 2 values from the body. (so body is something like {"value1":123, "value2":456}

1. Is it good practice to use viewsets for everything?
2. How should I implement a custom (multiply) function? I will have a serializer with the 2 params? And where to implement the code?
3. Am I doing things right?

EDIT1: I added the following code to my views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def test1(request):
    """
    Simple test
    """
    data = {
        "test": True
    }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then I added the route to my urls.py. But, as expected, the hyperlink doesnt show up in the api root.

I am seeing this in the API Root:
[image]

So this is missing my function based view.

Why is there a distinction here?

Comment: What feature of the `DefaultRouter` class do you like to have in your case?

Comment: api root, and the ease of use. I have used express (nodejs) routers before and the code is very similar

Comment: I have been using django-restframework in the same manner as above, there is nothing wrong with it. You don't need to use a serializer here unless you have need for it

Comment: my question isnt about the serializer. Its about having it in the api root (index)